# strptime() handles DST differently on different systems

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

I'm in the extremely unfortunate position of having to manually compensate (in a script, not just a one-time cleanup) for some incoming data that doesn't observe Daylight Savings Time conventions properly.  I'm trying to find the source of a difference in processing for some dates near the spring DST boundary, and ultimately correct for it.

An hourly sequence of incoming values might look like this:

```
dts <- c("03/12/2023 01:00:00",
         "03/12/2023 02:00:00",  # <- invalid, "should be" 03:00:00
         "03/12/2023 04:00:00",
         "03/12/2023 05:00:00")
```

On a MacOS system with R 4.2.2, `strptime` parses those like so:

```
(x <- strptime(dts, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "America/Los_Angeles"))
# [1] "2023-03-12 01:00:00 PST" "2023-03-12 02:00:00"
# [3] "2023-03-12 04:00:00 PDT" "2023-03-12 05:00:00 PDT"

x$zone
# [1] "PST" ""    "PDT" "PDT"
```

But on an Ubuntu 18.04 system with R 4.2.2, I get this:

```
(x <- strptime(dts, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "America/Los_Angeles"))
# [1] "2023-03-12 01:00:00 PST" "2023-03-12 02:00:00 PDT"
# [3] "2023-03-12 04:00:00 PDT" "2023-03-12 05:00:00 PDT"

x$zone
# [1] "PST" "PDT"    "PDT" "PDT"
```

Now, in the former case I can recognize the problem and correct it:

```
(bad <- is.na(x) & is.na(lubridate::dst(x)))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But in the latter case nothing is detected as wrong:

```
> (bad <- is.na(x) & is.na(lubridate::dst(x)))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The docs for `strptime` say:

> Input uses the POSIX function strptime and output the C99 function strftime.  However, not all OSes (notably Windows) provided strptime and many issues were found for those which did, so since 2000 R has used a fork of code from ‘⁠glibc⁠’.

So I'm not understanding where this issue is coming from, since theoretically `strptime` should be the same on all recent systems?

Any insight or ideas?

Comment: The so-called Olson database for timezone entries is know to vary between OSs which is why R ships its own. I would also *strongly* recommend to try this on *current* system.  Ubuntu 18.04 will possibly use a five-year old timezone database.  So maybe benchmark with (current) R 4.3.1 on a current OS release?  For what it is worth under R 4.3.1 on Ubuntu 23.04 I also get `"PST" "PDT" "PDT" "PDT"` for `x$zone`.  And yes, timezones were invented by the devil to drive us mad.  Just try to live in a UTC world.

Comment: The linux behavior has not changed in a while. On Ubuntu 16.04 (yes, still running :-/) and R-4.2.2, I get the same zones as @DirkEddelbuettel. As an alternative to a "UTC world", though, I suggest we all live in one big time zone, as the insightful [Ted Lasso suggested](https://lassoism.com/Ted-Lasso-quote.php?id=750) ;-)

Comment: More reference, I can repeat your macos behavior on Win11 (i.e., `x[2]` is `NA`).

Comment: Thanks all - so to sum up previous comments, it appears the behavior differs between *current* versions of Ubuntu and MacOS, right? (Not just old Ubuntu & new MacOS.)

Comment: I can reproduce the MacOS problem on 4.3.1, with MacOS 13.5 Beta

Comment: If you're looking for something which will throw an error on Mac, you can use `lubridate::as_datetime(dts, tz = "America/Los_Angeles", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Thanks @Mark - I actually think the behavior on Mac is far better than the behavior on Linux, because it lets me detect & fix the bad input.  On Linux it's not clear how to detect it.

Comment: @Mark - very helpful pointer to `as_datetime`, that might be the key to recovering here.  There are so many datetime parsing functions...

Comment: @KenWilliams yeah it depends what you want! I suppose some may want an error to be thrown, others for it to return the input for unprocessed strings. I imagine the results would be different if it were a column with a specific type

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the consensus is that this shouldn't really be happening, because modern R ships with both its own `strptime(3)` code from `glibc`, and its own version of the Olsen database.

I opened a ticket in R's bugzilla about it: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18581